# Is there a way to filter data showing in crystal reports from combobox value in another form

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, ado.net

I want to show a specified employee in crystal report when choosing his ID in another form, so i have to pass the combobox value from form2 to CrystalReport to filter with it...

I tried so many things, so many lines of code, but nothing seems to be helpful, and i'm in great need to finish this project

in Form2.cs

```
    private void btn_Imprimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RptSalarié r = new RptSalarié();
            r.DataSourceConnections[0].IntegratedSecurity = true;
            FrmImpression f = new FrmImpression(r);
            f.ShowDialog();
        }
```

in CrystalReport.cs

```
    private void FrmImpression_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code to pass combobox value to report? How are you sending the changed data? How do you filter? Update with code where you were stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
report.RecordSelectionFormula = "{Table.Field1} = '123'"
```

It's basically like a where statement in a normal SQL query and just filters your results.

Comment: it won't do anything because i want what is selected it the combobox, so either combobox.text or combobox.selecteditem

Comment: You cannot send combobox.selecteditem directly to report. Post code which shows your data to this report, so that one can understand how data is passed to report.